# Which is correct between Case A and Case B?

Tags: nouns, subject-verb-agreement, determiners

Based on the following sentence, which analysis is correct, Case A or Case B?

> The few minutes of attention he is giving you is sacrificial.

Case A:

- core noun : attention
- determiner : the few minutes of

So, Main verb is "singular is"

Case B:

- core noun : the few minutes
- determiner : of attention

So, Main verb is "singular is" (I think "few minutes" is considered singular noun)

I want to know this because It's a grammar test - The few minutes of attention he is giving you [are / is] sacrificial. So, two types of explanation are presented.

I want to know it more clearly with pure curiosity. (although not useful for practical English or English real life)

Comment: Given that the text remains valid if you remove ***either*** "few minutes [of]" ***or*** "attention", I'm tempted to say it's a matter of interpretation that could go either way. If the subject was ***only*** "The few minutes he's giving you...", I ***might*** be more inclined to treat that as a ***plural*** subject noun, but singular is also perfectly acceptable to me even then.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Please use the "Edit" button to add this to your question. It may help us give you more useful answers.